# Django: ModelMultipleChoiceField doesn't select initial choices

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

ModelMultipleChoiceField doesn't select initial choices and I can't make the following fix (link below) work in my example:

http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5247#comment:6

My models and form:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Contact(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Action(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, blank=True, null=True)
    from_company = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, verbose_name='Participant(s) from "Company"', blank=True, null=True)

class Action_Form(ModelForm):
    from_company = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Contact.objects.none(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    class Meta:
        model = Action
```

What I do and the results:

```
>>> contacts_from_company = Contact.objects.filter(company__exact=1) # "1" for test, otherwise a variable
>>> form = Action_Form(initial={'from_company': [o.pk for o in contacts_from_company]}) # as suggested in the fix
>>> print form['from_company']
<ul>
</ul>
>>> print contacts_from_company
[<Contact: test person>, <Contact: another person>]

>>> form2 = Action_Form(initial={'from_company': contacts_from_company})
>>> print form2['from_company']
<ul>
</ul>

>>> form3 = Action_Form(initial={'from_company': Contact.objects.all()})
>>> print form3['from_company']
<ul>
</ul>
```

The way I was hoping it would work:
1. My view gets "company" from request.GET
2. It then filters all "contacts" for that "company"
3. Finally, it creates a form and passes those "contacts" as "initial={...}"

**Two questions:**
**1. [not answered yet]** How can I make ModelMultipleChoiceField take those "initial" values?
**2. [answered]** As an alternative, can I pass a variable to Action_Form(ModelForm) so that in my ModelForm I could have:

```
from_company = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Contact.objects.filter(company__exact=some_id) # where some_id comes from a view
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will need to add an `__init__` method to `Action_Form` to set your initial values, remembering to call `__init__` on the base `ModelForm` class via **super**.

```
class Action_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Action_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['from_company'].queryset = Contact.object.filter(...
```

If you plan to pass your filter params as keyword args to `Action_Form`, you'll need to remove them prior invoking super:

```
myfilter = kwargs['myfilter']
del kwargs['myfilter']
```

or, probably better:

```
myfilter = kwargs.pop('myfilter')
```

For more information, here's another link referring to [Dynamic ModelForms in Django](http://www.rossp.org/blog/2008/dec/15/modelforms/).

Comment: Thanks! I tried the __init__ method but I don't know how to pass a variable to it, or to ModelForm. My form does not have initial values as it is the view that is supposed to pass them.

Could you please explain?

Comment: Thank you so much! This solves my problem, I can pass filter params now.  I wonder if they will patch the initial values issue any time soon though.

Comment: Removed original blog post link which now points to an adult website.

Answer (score 23):

I'm replying for 1)

> 1. How can I make ModelMultipleChoiceField take those "initial" values?

This could be done in your `Action_Form` `__init__` method using ModelMultipleChoiceField `initial` attribute.

As it says in the Django source code (*db/models/fields/related.py*)
in `def formfield(self, **kwargs)`:

```
        # If initial is passed in, it's a list of related objects, but the
        # MultipleChoiceField takes a list of IDs.
```

So you need to give it a list of IDs:

```
class Action_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Action_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['from_company'].initial = [c.pk for c in Contact.object.filter()]
```

Comment: You helped me a lot with that comment from the Django source code.

Comment: The method is called `__init__` not `init`.

Comment: Thanks @EduFelipe, I've updated my answer. This was a formatting issue with the StackOverflow "code" element.

Answer (score 13):

If previous answer wasn't straight-forward enough, I try to answer 1) again:

> 1. How can I make ModelMultipleChoiceField take those "initial" values?

You can leave `Action_Form` as it was in the original question, and just use this to render exactly what you want:

```
>>> form4 = Action_Form(initial={'from_company': Contact.objects.all().values_list('id',flat=True)})
>>> print form4['from_company']
```

Answer (score 12):

Answer to (1) question!

This will not work:

```
self.fields['from_company'].initial = [c.pk for c in Contact.object.filter()]
```

But this will **really work**:

```
self.initial['from_company'] = [c.pk for c in Contact.object.filter()]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the `Contact.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True)` if a **QuerySet** object, the **MultipleChoiceField** needs a list, see [in the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield)

To fix this, you need to convert the QuerySet to a list!

Exempla:

```
contacts = list(Contact.objects.values_list('id', flat=True))
form = Action_Form({'from_company': contacts})
```