# Adding a ManyToManyWidget to the reverse of a ManyToManyField in the Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Let's say I have a simple blog app in Django 1.4:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = …
    published_on = …
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = …
```

i.e. a post has many tags. On the Django admin, I get a nice little `<select multi>` if I include `tags` in the `fields` for the `PostAdmin`. Is there an easy way to include the list of the posts (as a simple `<select multi>`) in the `TagAdmin`? I tried putting `fields = ['name', 'posts']` in the `TagAdmin` and got an `ImproperlyConfigured` error. (same result for `post_set`).

I'm alright with Django, so could whip up a proper AdminForm and Admin object, but I'm hoping there a Right Way™ to do it.

Comment: are you looking for inline edits? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models

Comment: You can set up intermediary model using `through` attribute and set up few inlines in Admin. But that is far from beautiful solution. Take a look at this ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/897

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing -- seems simple enough. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 33):

This is possible to do with a custom form.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms

from models import Post, Tag

class PostAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tags = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        Tag.objects.all(),
        widget=admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple('Tags', False),
        required=False,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk:
            self.initial['tags'] = self.instance.tags.values_list('pk', flat=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(PostAdminForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if instance.pk:
            instance.tags.clear()
            instance.tags.add(*self.cleaned_data['tags'])
        return instance

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PostAdminForm

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

That `False` in there can be replaced with a `True` if you want vertically stacked widget.

Comment: Um... Am I missing something, or is this totally missing the point of the OP? The point being "list of the posts in the TagAdmin". TagAdmin, not PostAdmin. The approach looks fine though.

Comment: Maybe swap TagAdmin and PostAdmin.

Comment: Maybe. Also, save won't work this way for when adding a new object, because Django admin calls it with `form.save(commit=False)`, thus no pk. Instead, move that code to 'TagAdmin.save_model(...)'.

Comment: Good call. I probably should actually test that code, rather than just write it in a browser though ;)

Answer (score 14):

A bit late to the party, but this is the solution that works for me (no magic):

```
# admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from models import Post

class TagPostInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Post.tags.through
    extra = 1

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [TagPostInline]

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't really do what the question asks, which is for a select[multiple] widget.

Answer (score 8):

Modify your models to add reverse field:

```py
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    published_on = models.DateTimeField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    posts = models.ManyToManyField('blog.Post', through='blog.post_tags')
```

Then in standard way add field to ModelAdmin:

```py
#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('posts', )

admin.site.register(Tag, TagAdmin)
```

Comment: This breaks migrations, syncdb etc. There is a hacky workaround: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1295/ but I haven't tried it with the new Django migrations

Comment: With Django 1.11, this actually works fine now, as far as I can tell.  `makemigrations` generates a migration for the redundant M2M field, but it applies without problems.

Comment: One usually desirable outcome with this solution is that the 'add another' (+) button is shown besides the reverse field, without any additional work as otherwise required (using `ManyToManyRel`, `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper`).

Comment: Shouldn't it be in the docs or there is some caveat?

Comment: I see high coupling. What else?

Answer (score 4):

Matthew's solution didn't work for me (Django 1.7) when creating a new entry, so I had to change it a bit. I hope it's useful for someone :)

```
class PortfolioCategoriesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    items = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        PortfolioItem.objects.all(),
        widget=admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple('Portfolio items', False),
        required=False
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PortfolioCategoriesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk:
            initial_items = self.instance.items.values_list('pk', flat=True)
            self.initial['items'] = initial_items

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['commit'] = True
        return super(PortfolioCategoriesForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def save_m2m(self):
        self.instance.items.clear()
        self.instance.items.add(*self.cleaned_data['items'])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add a symmetrical many to many filter this way.

Credit goes to
https://gist.github.com/Grokzen/a64321dd69339c42a184

```
from django.db import models

class Pizza(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, related_name='pizzas')

class Topping(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

### pizza/admin.py ###

from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

from .models import Pizza, Topping

class PizzaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  filter_horizonal = ('toppings',)

class ToppingAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
  pizzas = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=Pizza.objects.all(), 
    required=False,
    widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
      verbose_name=_('Pizzas'),
      is_stacked=False
    )
  )

  class Meta:
    model = Topping

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ToppingAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    if self.instance and self.instance.pk:
      self.fields['pizzas'].initial = self.instance.pizzas.all()

  def save(self, commit=True):
    topping = super(ToppingAdminForm, self).save(commit=False)

    if commit:
      topping.save()

    if topping.pk:
      topping.pizzas = self.cleaned_data['pizzas']
      self.save_m2m()

    return topping

class ToppingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  form = ToppingAdminForm

admin.site.register(Pizza, PizzaAdmin)
admin.site.register(Topping, ToppingAdmin)
```