# Pre-populating forms with a select field with several values in Django 

Tags: django, forms, select, populate

I have tried quite a few things but I still don't know how can I populate a `select field` in Django. The following example, adds a dictionary with a select field with a `name='tags'` attribute.

```
data = {}
for tag in tags:
  data['tags'] = tag.name
form = Form(initial=data)
```

As it is expected, the loop is overwriting the key 'tags', so it only prevails the last value (and indeed, the form shows the last value). I expected that maybe passing a list would work:

```
data = {}
l = []
for tag in tags:
  l.append(tag.name)
data['tags'] = l
form = Form(initial=data)
```

But in this case, it just doesn't work.

As you can imagine, I'm using a form similar to this:

```
class NewTopicForm(forms.Form):
  ... some fields
  tags = ChoiceField(
            widget=forms.Select(), 
            choices=SOME_CHOICES
         )
```

What is the correct way to populate a form with a select field when I need to add several values?.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I tried the following in accordance with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3915048/460147):

```
data = {'tags': tags.values_list('name',flat=True) }
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Am I missing something?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want [MultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield) if you want the initial values to be a list.

Comment: Beautiful. I had to change it to tags = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={ // some attributes }), choices=TAGS_CHOICES), but that worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!.